# Unable to access to EC2 TCP/IP server from university wireless network

Tags: java, android, tcp, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on a communication application on android platform that mainly utilizes TCP / IP socket connection. I'm running my server on one of my EC2 instance and my application has no problem accessing to TCP socket server on EC2 when i try it at home. However, even tho I have enabled every TCP / IP ports accessible from my security group, i can't access to my tcp/ip server at all from uni wireless network. Is this because I'm using Socket? or the port im using is banned from my uni network? or what would be the problem and what is the solution? Thank you guys

Comment: Use Wireshark to see what is going on.  Check with your network administrator to see what the specific configuration might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

public networks like university's ones don't usually allow to use any other ports then 80 or 443